# Custom colors for tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

When a user marks a tag as favorite questions with that tag appear in a different color in the question list.

How about allowing the user to choose what color to use for a particular tag?
Many questions will contain multiple tags.. so possibly either just choose one, or use 2-3 pixel wide colored bars on the left-hand side of a listing.

I'm no graphic artist.  Perhaps someone else can suggest a method of colorization.  I would just like to be able to quickly scan the list for a color.

Edit:
To add some clarification on why I think this would be useful.  For me personally, and I imagine quite a few others, I have experience in a wide range of technologies in the Microsoft stack. Anything from Winforms to WPF to ASP (classic, .NET, and MVC) to SQL, to.. etc..  At any given moment I may feel like helping someone with Winforms but have no interest in ASP, or vice-versa. I've added all the Microsoft-related technology tags that I have experience in to my favorites.. so now the question list is just a sea of orange for me.  Being able to quickly pick out one or two tags of interest at that particular moment would be of use to me.

I am aware of the tag search functionality.  This doesn't quite do it for me though.  First, a search requires effort that a quick visual scan does not.  Second, if I don't find something on my first pass, it's super easy to readjust my visual scan whereas a search requires, well, a search.  Third, I can let the visual scan influence my mood.  I may not be in the mood to answer ASP net questions right now, but if I see a lot of purple (for example) I might be persuaded to alter my mood and provide a helpful answer to somebody.

Comment: I'm happy to have criticism, but down-voting without leaving a comment doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: See the [meta-help]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. For feature requests that usually means: *I don't think this feature would be useful or needs to be implemented*.

Comment: I didn't downvote; I upvoted instead. However, this suggestion was not very constructive : we already have another color for favourite tags, and adding another will make this so messy.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80250/color-code-favorite-tags (can't close because different site)

Comment: @Jamie: I agree.  Complexity is certainly undesired in most situations.  This could definitely be an optional setting - allowing the user to choose the level of complexity they want to see on screen.

Comment: So you're talking about something like a 10 pixel wide swatch of sorts, just enough for easy visual identification? Hadn't thought of that before, kind of interesting.

Comment: @TimPost: Yes, exactly.  Something small, but easy to scan with your eye.

Answer (score 9):

I use a little userscript that does custom tag highlighting:

```
// Different kinds of highlighting
function h1(t) {
   t.css('border', '2px solid red');
};

function h2(t) {
   t.css('background-color', '#F1E0EA');
};

// Select highlighted tags
var specialtags = null;
if (document.location.host == 'stackoverflow.com') {
   specialtags = {
      'c++11': h2,
      haskell: h1
      // ...
   };
}
else if (document.location.host == 'meta.stackoverflow.com') {
   specialtags = {
      bug: h1
   };
}

// Check all the tags
if (specialtags) {
   $('.post-tag').each(function(i, t){
      t = $(t);
      var tagname = t.text();
      if (tagname in specialtags) {
         specialtags[tagname](t);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Nice, I do like when people go to the effort to do this themselves when it really is a personal preference kind of thing. To add the OP's question you could use `$(".post-tag.user-tag")` to find select favorite tags rather than hardcode them

Comment: This is great for people that use browsers that have this kind of functionality.  But people like me that use Internet Explorer and Safari don't have this option.

Comment: @Dan-o All browsers can use bookmarklets. Just write a shortcut wrapper around the provided code and stick it in your favourites in IE. P.S. Did you lose a bet or why are you using IE? :-)